# Why the location for Partition entry in MBR doesn't contain partition entry?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, mbr, boot-partition, bootsector

I'm learning file system recently. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout) says the partition table is located at 0x01BE, but when I check my USB drive(NTFS) by a binary tool, there are some words there "Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to restart". It doesn't look like partition table. Why? Where is the partition table?

Comment: Are you sure the disk is MBR and not GPT?

Comment: @Ramhound  Yes. I checked the property of volume in disk management. It is MBR

Comment: Do you check the whole device (in Linux like `/dev/sdc`)? Or the partition (in Linux like `/dev/sdc1`)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I use windows. I check by Disk Designator, such as G: or H:. Is this correct? How could I check the whole device?

Comment: AFAIK Windows likes to pretend a filesystem is equivalent to the partition it's in; and it likes to pretend a single partition is equivalent to the disk it belongs to. I would say a drive letter is assigned to a filesystem. Most likely what your binary tool read is a partition. The partition table does not belong to any partition (at least it shouldn't).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  You are right. I shouldn't check by drive letter. That's not the first sector of physical disk, but the partition. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I cannot post an educative answer because I don't really know Windows. To anyone who can: don't let my comments stop you; I'm not going to post an answer; go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture says more than a thousand words..

[image]

64 bytes at offset 0x01BE (446), with room for 4 entries of 16 bytes each. In this case only one entry is used to define a GPT Protective Partition as the partitions are actually defined in the GUID partition table (GPT).

Same sector interpreted as partition table:

[image]

This EE type partition typically occupies the entire drive or the 4 bytes for LBA sectors is maxed out (0xFFFFFFFF - 4294967295 - 2TB) as we see on this 4 TB drive so that 'legacy' partition tools and editors perceive the drive as fully allocated. And this is also where the '2 TB' maximum partition size for legacy/MBR partition tables originates.

[image]

An awesome resource for this type of stuff is the "The Starman", https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GPT.htm.